# Try to setup jitsi behind a apache2 reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, jitsi-meet

Iam using a ubuntu 18.04 linux VM as a reverse proxy to forward https subdomains to intern targets f.e. guacamole.mydomain.com and jitsi.mydomain.com.
Each system is a seperate linux VM.

*public ip --> web reverse proxy 192.168.2.10 --> guacamole.mydomain.com 192.168.2.20 and jitsi.mydomain.com 192.168.2.30*

guacamole is working as expected but iam facing some issues with fowarding https to jitsi.mydomain.com.
All other ports are directly forwarded to jitsi without a proxy.

i created two conf files in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled** one for jitsi and one for guacamole and generated a lets encrypt cert with **certbot --apache**.

When i try to open jits.mydomain.com from outside, i get the following Error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Within the network jitsi is reachable via https, so what did i miss?

unfortunately iam not very familiar with proxy and apache.

thanks in advance guys.

**jitsi.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName jitsi.mydomain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.30:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.30:80/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jitsi.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**jitsi-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName jitsi.mydomain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.30:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.30:80/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jitsi.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jitsi.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**guacamole.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName guacamole.mydomain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 <Location />
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     ProxyPass http://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
     ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/
     ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /guacamole /
 </Location>
 <Location /websocket-tunnel>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     ProxyPass ws://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
     ProxyPassReverse ws://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
 </Location>
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/tunnel" dontlog
 CustomLog  /var/log/apache2/guac.log common env=!dontlog
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =guacamole.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**guacamole-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName guacamole.mydomain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ProxyPass /.well-known !
 <Location />
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     ProxyPass http://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
     ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/
     ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /guacamole /
 </Location>
 <Location /websocket-tunnel>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     ProxyPass ws://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
     ProxyPassReverse ws://192.168.2.20:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
 </Location>
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/tunnel" dontlog
 CustomLog  /var/log/apache2/guac.log common env=!dontlog

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guacamole.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guacamole.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon your question while looking for a solution of a different problem on Jitsi but I think you'll find a useful solution in this page:
https://debamax.com/blog/2020/03/18/installing-jitsi-behind-a-reverse-proxy/

It's not my solution. I'm just trying to help.

Cheers